# form is not updating

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I was trying crud in node js but my update is not working. I was trying to update for two days but it is not working. The form successfully adds and delete id.
form

```
<a href="/edit/<%= admins[i]._id %>" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a>

<form action="/edit" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" name="title" value="<%= admins.title %>"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="URL" name="url"
            value="<%= admins.url %>"></div>
    <div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" name="description"
            value="<%= admins.description %>"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Keywords" name="keywords" value="<%= admins.keywords %>">
    </div>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="edit" class="btn btn-primary" form="myForm">
```

adminController.js

```
 router.get('/edit', async (req,res) => {
        const id  = req.params;
        const admins = await Admin.findById(id);
        res.render('/seo', {
            admins
        });
    });

    router.get('/edit/:id', async (req,res) => {
        const { id } = req.params;
        await Admin.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, req.body, { new: true });
        res.redirect('/seo');
    });
```

Comment: What is the type of Id, ObjectId or hex string?

Comment: It is the type of ObjectId

Comment: in the findOneAndUpdate, see if it handles without ObjectId wrap else convert to ObjectId as `mongoose.ObjectId(id)`